# <a routerLink="#Profile">Profile</a> Is not woking in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am facing an issue while using `<a  routerLink="/Profile">Profile</a>` in index.html file. The anchor tag didnot work properly. I placed header menu on index.html and want to add the following code for Routing in angular 4

```
<a href="#Profile" routerLink="/Profile" routerLinkActive="active">
<span class="icon-cogs"></span>Profile</a>
```

The `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`is placed in app.component.html

The Same line code `<a  routerLink="/Profile">Profile</a>` working file when i put it in any other component but not working in index.html

Comment: Also remove `href="#Profile"`.

Comment: Can you provide us your project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should not put this code inside index.html, it won't work, it should be inside
>   component.

routerLink be like this :

```
routerLink="/Profile"
```

So keep it like :

```
<a routerLink="/Profile" routerLinkActive="active">
```

For more detail please read :

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Still not working. whrn i put the same code in any component it is working.